# How do you use Varaibles within an override function from an inherited class

Tags: c#, function, class, unity-game-engine

I have two classes (one of which is inherited from the other) and i wish to override one of the functions i have defined in the class however when attempting to use variables defined in the inherited class it gives me the error "Variable is inaccessible due to its protection level" I'm guessing this is because it is trying to use the variables in the inherited class not in the class that the override is in but i'm not sure how to get unity to use the variables in the class not the ones in the inherited class.
Example:

```
public class InheritedClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int x;
    public virtual void Divideby2(int num) {
        Debug.Log(num/2);
    }
}
```

```
public class Inheritor1 : InheritedClass
{
}
```

```
public class Inheritor2 : InheritedClass
{
    public override void DivideBy2(int num) {
        Debug.Log(num/x)
    }
}
```

This is a simplified version of what I have where InheritedClass is a class/script which I have multiple other class/scripts inheriting from (Inheritor1 and Inheritor2) however I want to override the function in one of the scripts (Inheritor2) by using its x variable but in this case I would get the error: Assets\Scripts\Inheritor2.cs(4,14): error CS0122: 'InheritedClass.x' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Actual code

```
public class Weapon : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject AttackPrefab, SpecialPrefab, ThisWeaponPrefab, AttackSequenceFinisherPrefab;
    private Vector3 MousePosition;
    [SerializeField] private float SpecialCooldown, AttackCooldown, FinisherCooldown, AttackSequenceTimeToEnd;
    private float TimePassed, RotationY, TimeToHold, AttackSequenceEndTime, SpecialCooldownTimer, FinisherCooldownTimer;
    public int MaxAttackSequence;
    [HideInInspector] public int AttackSequence;
    private bool CanSpecial, CanAttack;

    public virtual void AttackDetermine(int num)
    {
        MousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
        if (MousePosition.x < 0) {MousePosition.x = 0;}
        if (MousePosition.x > Screen.width) {MousePosition.x = Screen.width;}
        if (MousePosition.y < 0) {MousePosition.x = 0;}
        if (MousePosition.y > Screen.height) {MousePosition.x = Screen.height;}
        MousePosition.y -= (Screen.height / 2);
        MousePosition.x -= (Screen.width / 2);
        RotationY = Mathf.Atan2(MousePosition.y, MousePosition.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90;
        if ((num == 2) & (Character.instance.BusyTime <= 0) & (SpecialCooldownTimer >= 0)){
            CanSpecial = true;
        }
        else if ((num == 1) & (Character.instance.BusyTime <= 0) & (FinisherCooldownTimer <= 0)) {
            CanAttack = true;
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Bow : Weapon
{
    public Bow Instance;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public override void AttackDetermine(int num) {
        MousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
        if (MousePosition.x < 0) {MousePosition.x = 0;}
        if (MousePosition.x > Screen.width) {MousePosition.x = Screen.width;}
        if (MousePosition.y < 0) {MousePosition.x = 0;}
        if (MousePosition.y > Screen.height) {MousePosition.x = Screen.height;}
        MousePosition.y -= (Screen.height / 2);
        MousePosition.x -= (Screen.width / 2);
        RotationY = Mathf.Atan2(MousePosition.y, MousePosition.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90;
        Vector3 relativePos = Character.instance.InGameCharacter.transform.position - Enemy.instance.InGameCharacter.transform.position;
        RotationEnemy = Quaternion.LookRotation(relativePos, Vector3.up);
        if ((num == 2) & (Character.instance.BusyTime <= 0) & (SpecialCooldownTimer >= 0)){
            CanSpecial = true;
        }
        else if ((num == 1) & (Character.instance.BusyTime <= 0) & (FinisherCooldownTimer <= 0)) {
            CanAttack = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Should add that the script for the bow is not entirely finished (as i started trying to fix this error) and will give another seperate error about RotationEnemy you can you remove it for now or properly define it as a variable

Comment: If this is a simplified example .. can you post the actual code? .. even after fixing your typos here your "issue" [does not reproduce](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1DK9kY) ... my guess would be that `x` has no access modifier and thereby indeed is implicitly **private** to your base class ....

Comment: In the original code, is `x` by any chance `private`? If so, consider replacing it with a `protected int X {get; set;}`

Comment: To add to what Fildor said, you may also have omitted the `public` declaration on the `x` variable which would make it `private` by default.

Comment: I've added the the original code and will try replacing private with protected

Comment: Yes: you are trying to use `private` fields. That won't fly. You need to make them at least `protected`. Or do something completely different.

Comment: And unrelated: I am not that versed in unity, but `public` _fields_ make me flinch.

Comment: Thank you Fildor. Replacing private with protected has solved the error

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with my use of private instead of protected
for example I should have used:

```
protected int x
```

Instead of

```
private int x
```

Comment: In the context of that specific problem: yes. On a wider scale, people probably would recommend to prefer "composition over inheritance". Which is worthwhile to learn about, even if going "protected" is fine for you here.